# How can I create table from parquet file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, parquet

Given a parquet file how can I create the table associated with it into my redshift database? Oh the format of the parquet file is snappy.

Comment: [Amazon Redshift Can Now COPY from Parquet and ORC File Formats](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-redshift-can-now-copy-from-parquet-and-orc-file-formats/)

Comment: Is your real problem that you don't know what columns are stored in the file?

Comment: @Parsifal yes, I don't want to guess on the column types but I can't COPY the data unless I create the table first.

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with multiple files, especially over a long term, then I think the best solution is to upload them to an S3 bucket and run a [Glue crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html).

In addition to populating the Glue data catalog, you can also use this information to configure external tables for [Redshift Spectrum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-using-spectrum.html), and create your on-cluster tables using `create table as select`.

If this is just a one-off task, then I've used `parquet-tools` in the past. The version that I've used is a Java library, but I see that [there's also a version on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/).